# IntelliJ autocomplete path

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, autocomplete, sails.js, intellij-14

I can't figure how configure IntelliJ to autocomplete path for web resources correctly.
My project is in Node.js with Sails.js framework. Assets are structured like this :

assets :

- js
- images
- styles
- ...

Under IntelliJ if I put /assets/js/myscript.js autocomplete is working cause assets is under root folder. But only content of assets is deployed by sails so my path have to be /js/myscript.js but IntelliJ don't know this path...
I try to mark folders as "Resources root" but same result.

I'm on IntelliJ 14.0.3. If someone have an idea let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What folders are you marking as Resources root? You should probably mark only one folder, I mean /assets as Resource root because it is the only web root in sails project.

Comment: I try to make assets as root or each subfolder and same results, Intellij doesn't know /js/..... but /assets/js/... works

Comment: Then I have not neither idea how to fix it nor inteliJ to try

Comment: Have you tried configuring web content resources in the web facet? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-static-content-resources.html. Seems like adding web resources root pointing to assets should solve this problem.

Comment: When I try to add a new facet I have "Nothing here" I can't add facets...